# How to set maximum characters per line in tinyMCE, version 5.0.11?

Tags: javascript, angular, tinymce

So I have a angular 8 application and I am using tinyMCE

and I want to set the maximum characters per line in the textArea of tinymce.

Of course I googled a lot. But I can't find any solution.
[image]

So this is to long. So I want that the user can only put half of the text of the showing line.

So  I want to archive maximum characters per line not in total.

But how to archive this?

Thank you.

So this is input field of tinyMce:

```
        <ng-container *ngIf="is('HtmlDisplay')">
          <editor
            [init]="tinyMCESettings"
            name="html"
            ngModel
            #html="ngModel"
          ></editor>
        </ng-container>
```

and this is ts script:

```
 public tinyMCESettings = {
    base_url: '/assets/tinymce',
    suffix: '.min',
    plugins: 'link lists image code advlist',
    toolbar: 'undo redo | bold italic | bullist numlist outdent indent | link | image | code'
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can limit the width of the text being entered by modifying the TinyMCE CSS. For example, using `content_style`,

```
content_style: "body { margin: 1rem auto; max-width: 900px; }"
```

There are also two predefined stylesheets that set larger margins - `document` and `writer`. You may also find these useful. You can apply them with `content_css`; for example:

```
content_css: "writer"
```

or

```
content_css: "document"
```

Comment: Thank you. Very nice.